# JQuery $.post is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, servicestack

This is my Index.cshtml file (I'm learning MVC .NET), and when I click on the Add button to add a new user, this user is not added when I go and check my Api.
I know that both the route (api/users) and the Json object are correct, and the script is being rendered.
I'am using Visual Studio 2017 for Mac and my Api service is Service Stack.

```
@model dynamic
```

﻿    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Protein Tracker";
        Layout = "../Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }

```
@section scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function AddNewUser(){
            var goal = $('#goal').val();
            var name = $('#name ').val();

            $.post("api/users", { 'Name' : name, 'Goal' : goal });
}
</script>

}


<h2>Protein Tracker</h2>
<div>
    <label for="select-user">Select a user</label>
    <select id="select-uder"></select>
</div>
<hr /> <!-- horizontal rule -->
<div>
    <h2>Add new user</h2>
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input id="name" type="text" /><br />
    <label for="goal">Goal</label>
    <input id="goal" type="text" /><br />
    <input id="add-new-user-button" type="button" value="Add" onclick="AddNewUser()" />
 </div>
```

Comment: Not sure if it will help, but you could try wrapping your HTML in a <form method="POST"> </form> tag.

Comment: You have an extra space in `$('#name ')`.

Comment: When you debug, where specifically does it fail?  Is there a JavaScript error on the browser's debugging console?  Is the POST request made?  Does it contain the data you expect?  What is the server's response?  We need more information.

Comment: Please make sure your API is defined with [httppost] attribute.

Comment: Can you post the code for the controller?

Comment: Please update your question to show your Request DTO for your `/api/users` method as well as the raw HTTP Request/Response headers sent using something like Chrome WebInspector of Fiddler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the help guys, I tried everything everyone suggested, but when I used the Chrome WebInspector (like @mythz suggested) I discovered that "$" was not defined, so I understood that my code was not being recognized as JQuery or something like that. And when I added the following line of code it worked as expected:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```